# How to add hyperlink on specific word

Tags: html, contenteditable

I am planning to develop a web application which will be used to published articles.Now i want to know how content is written something like wiki where some specific words contain hyperlinks.

In this content you can see Hashtable, Java programmer, JSTL foreac tag for this are marked has a hyperlink. Is there any tools exist or i have to associate hyperlink manually.

```
HashMap in JSP, or any other Map implementation e.g. <a>Hashtable</a>, I personally prefer (JSTL foreach tag for this). As a <a>Java programmer</a>, I often have urge to use Java code directly in JSP using scriptlet, but that's a bad coding practice, and one should always avoid that. Infact by smart use of expression language and JSTL core tag library, you can reduce lot of Java code from JSP. In our last post, we have seen example of JSTL foreach tag to loop over List, but not a Map, and that creates a doubt in one of m
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you need to implement this in Javascript. The problem is horribly complicated because you need to iterate over a list of `search_words` while simultaneously walking through the `body` searching for longest matches. The *longest* match part is what makes this tricky: You want to match the text "Java Programmer", not just the word "Java".

You also want to ignore whitespace and capitalisation problems. I strongly recommend you build on an existing solution such as the open-source [MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) project to save reinventing a complicated wheel.